# Assign included loaded javascript to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a simple offline javascript application that will be distributed to clients in a CD or some other media. In the head of the HTML file, I load the latest 'jquery' script, followed by another file ("webpages.js") which content is the following string in json format:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Google",
    "url":"http://www.google.com"
  }
]
```

In a subsequent javascript file, I wish to access the data through a variable, e.g. `websites`. I have successfully tried the following two options.

**Option 1:** Edit the file websites.js to directly assign the variable, i.e.

```
websites = 
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Google",
    "url":"http://www.google.com"
  }
]
```

**Option 2:** Use jquery's getJSON, i.e.

```
$.getJSON('websites.js', function(websites){
  // use websites data here
})
```

I wish to avoid the above options because (a) I wish to retain the integrity of the file "websites.js"; and (b) because using jquery's getJSON() only works in the Firefox browser, but not in Chrome (haven't tested with other browsers).

So, the question is: Is it possible to assign the string in the included "websites.js" to a variable? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why wouldn't getJSON work in chrome? It should work in all major browsers.

Comment: Because of security. XHR requests from one `file://` url to another is prohibited in chrome, unless it is started with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

Comment: Note that `websites = $.getJSON('websites.js')` will _NOT_ put the json data in the websites variable.

Comment: thanks @Eric for noticing that. I fixed it above. I hope I got it correct this time.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use your **option 1**, but call var in websites.js by any other name (say: myWsVar001), and in main file just assign : `var websites = myWsVar001;`

Comment: I think it would be redundant to do so. I can actually do **Option 1** and access the variable `websites` from the main script file.

Comment: another approachcould be anonymous wraper in websites.js... but still can't get your idea - to keep data in some "vacuum" condition without assinging it to ANY var. IMHO

Comment: In the hope of easing some automation, I was hoping I could just download the websites data keep it as it is without additional editing. Of course, I could come up with a short script to assign the data to `var websites`, but then, I was thinking if I can keep everything in javascript.